# How to use composition correctly?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

```
[DataContract(Name = "jobDateTimeFilterRequest", Namespace = Constants.ManagementNamespace)]
public class JobDateTimeFilterRequest : TimeFrame
{
    [DataMember(Name = "jobType")]
    public BackgroundJobType JobType { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "timeFrame", Namespace = Constants.ManagementNamespace)]
public class TimeFrame
{
    [DataMember(Name = "from")]
    public DateTime From { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "to")]
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use composition instead of inheritance.
To do this I will need to create:

```
[DataContract(Name = "jobFilterRequest", Namespace = Constants.ManagementNamespace)]
public class JobFilterRequest
{
    [DataMember(Name = "jobType")]
    public BackgroundJobType JobType { get; set; }
}
```

And `JobDateTimeFilterRequest` will be like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "jobDateTimeFilterRequest", Namespace = Constants.ManagementNamespace)]
public class JobDateTimeFilterRequest
{
    [DataMember(Name = "jobType")]
    public JobFilterRequest JobFilter { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "timeFrame")]
    public TimeFrame TimeFrame{ get; set; }
}
```

I'm I right? Or it's incorrect understanding of composition?

Comment: That's one way to do composition, yes. What question do you have that's on topic on Stack Overflow? :P

Comment: Generally you are right. You've placed instance of base class in state of derived class. But you should not forget about incapsulation, in current realisation it is possible to get inconsistent state of `JobDateTimeFilterRequest` object, for example by setting TimeFrame null. Think about consistent state of objects

Comment: @agent5566 Thanks, how can I handle this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "composition over inheritance" tenet usually applies to objects with behavior, not simple data structures. The reason is, it makes it easier to extend the system with new *functionality*. In contrast, just introducing new data isn't changing the system per se.

In your case, as long as you don't override the properties and they remain public auto-properties, inheriting from `TimeFrame` will probably be just as good as having a `TimeFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you are right. You've placed instance of base class in state of derived class. But you should not forget about incapsulation, in current realisation it is possible to get inconsistent state of `JobDateTimeFilterRequest` object, for example by setting `TimeFrame` null. Think about consistent state of objects it dends on business logic in lagerly. I don't know your business logic but your case could be done for example by taking constructor parameter with private setter of the `TimeFrame` property for example. Note that we are talking about general case but there is `WCF` logic which perhaps can be potentially broken by`private` modifier

Probably it would be like this (i'm ignoring `WCF` attributes and logic):

```
public class JobDateTimeFilterRequest
{
    public JobFilterRequest JobFilter { get; set; }

    public TimeFrame TimeFrame{ get; private set; }

    public JobDateTimeFilterRequest(TimeFrame timeFrame)
    {
        this.TimeFrame = timeFrame;
    }
}
```

Comment: i've added simple example but i agree with @guillaume31 that composition may be redundant here